# $9$ receipts in a basket, numbered from $0$ to $8$ no repetition. If 3 are picked with replacement, and are arranged in (First)(Second)(Third) order.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $9$ receipts in a basket, numbered as whole numbers from $0$ to $8$ without repetition. If $3$ receipts are picked with replacement, and if the three picked numbers are arranged such that the number picked first is placed as the hundred's digit, the number picked second is placed as ten's digit, and the number picked third is placed as the unit's digit of a number, then what is the probability for that number to be more than $499$?

**My approach**

The smallest possible number is 000 and the largest possible number is $888$. So, the number of elements in our sample space is $888 - 000 + 1 = 889$.

The favorable number of cases are from 500 to 888 inclusive. So, the number of favorable cases is $888 - 500 + 1 = 389$.

Hence, the proabability that the number will be greater than $499$ is simply $\dfrac{389}{889}$.

Is my solution approach correct? If not, where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Note that the digit $9$ is not included, so you are overcounting the sample space. (Your count includes impossible numbers like $199$, $392$, etc.) Instead, there should be $9^3 = 729$ possibilities. As for the probability, here's a hint: do the second and third tickets matter at all?

Comment: @Theophile. Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was doing wrong. For example, the counting technique I used actually counted 009, 019, 029 etc. which can not be formed using original eight numbers.

Comment: Sample set: 
First position can be filled in 9 ways.
Second position can be filled in 9 ways.
Third position can be filled in 9 ways.
Size of sample space = 9^3

Favorable cases:
First position can be filled in 4ways (5, 6, 7, 8). Second and third position can be filled in 9 ways each.

P = 4 * 9 * 9 / (9 * 9 * 9) = 4/9

Comment: Glad to help. That's the correct solution; feel free to write up your thoughts with the solution as an answer to your own question. (Also note that you don't actually need the second and third position; as soon as you draw the first ticket, you can tell whether you've won or not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the comments, the tens digit and ones digit are irrelevant.  There are $9$ choices for the hundreds digit, and the number will be greater than 499 if and only if the hundreds digit is an element in $\{5,6,7,8\}.$

So, the probability is $\displaystyle \frac{4}{9}.$

There is no need to do any computations beyond what happens in the hundreds digit.